# Let $A$ be a square matrix. Prove that $A$ ~ $I_n$ if and only if $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$ has only the trivial solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, alternative-proof

I'm studying Linear Algebra for the second time, using Hoffmann & Kunze. Currently I'm trying to prove the following theorem:

> **Theorem 7**. If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then $A$ is row-equivalent to the $n \times n$ identity matrix if and only if the system of equations $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$ has only the trivial solution $\vec{x} = \vec{0}$.

The given proof in the textbook is, I find, obscure, and I don't understand it at all, so I came up with my own proof. However, it depends on $det(A) \neq 0$ and I'm not sure if this assumption can be made.

I rewrote the theorem as:

> Let $A$ be a square matrix. Prove that $A$ ~ $I_n$ if and only if $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$ has only the trivial solution.

**My proof:**

Let $det(A) \neq 0$. Then $rref(A) = I_n$. If $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$, then $det(A\vec{x}) = 0 \rightarrow \vec{x} = \vec{0}$, so $\vec{0}$ is indeed the only solution.

The problem with my proof is, even if it's correct, the authors only introduce determinants around page $200$ and this theorem is from chapter $1$. So really I'm looking for a proof that does not rely upon determinants.

Comment: It is just an incomplete argument. To complete it you would need, for example, to prove that equivalence to the identity is a condition that is equivalent (logically) to the determinant not being zero.

Comment: Also, the second "then" in your argument is not explained. If I were evaluating you I would not assume that you know why that is true. You would need to explain it.

Comment: The quantity $A\vec x$ is a vector. What, then is $\det(A\vec x)$?

Comment: Gaps in the argument notwithstanding, you’ve only shown one direction of the equivalence.

Comment: By the way, the argument in your book, is much more than just the proof of that theorem. It is an algorithm that is the single most important tool that you will have in an introduction to linear algebra. You could perfectly forget about that theorem. But you should never skip that proof.

Comment: @user647486 I could fill in the gaps that you complain are lacking. But then proving something would be an infinite regress, only to be stopped at definitions, or perhaps axioms. You behave as if you're grading me for some reason.

Comment: @amd yes, indeed I have only tried to show one direction of the proof. I wouldn't try to prove the other direction before proving what I'm attempting to prove first.

Comment: You can try to hide behind that justification to give very incomplete arguments. Take into account two things. (1) all these problems are very trivial exercises. Not hard theorems. Proving them is mainly a way to learn the techniques and arguments that are typical in linear algebra. (2) Even though they are so basic, you are struggling with them You even found 'obscure' the proof in the book. This means, you should really get into every detail possible in those arguments. Not doing so is only your loss.

Comment: @user647486 it's not a bad justification. For example, Imre Lakatos uses the same "infinite regress" justification in the book "Proofs and Refutations". Step down from the heavens and supply this peasant a proof, to prove you math-god level skills.

Comment: You tick [all the items](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank_(person)#Common_characteristics). So, have fun.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the elementary row operations correspond to left multiplication by elementary row operation matrices. (To figure out what these matrices are, apply the given row operation to the identity matrix!)

Therefore, if $A$ is row-equivalent to $I$, then there exist elementary matrices $E_1, \ldots, E_k$ such that

$$E_1 E_2 \ldots E_k A = I.$$

Hence,

\begin{align*}
Ax = 0 &\implies E_1 E_2 \ldots E_k A x = E_1 E_2 \ldots E_k 0 \\
&\implies x = I x = E_1 E_2 \ldots E_k 0 = 0.
\end{align*}

Combine this with the obvious fact $A0 = 0$, and we get that $x = 0$ is the unique solution to the matrix equation.